# What does this symbol on my dash mean? GMC W4500

Tags: truck, gmc, dashboard

[image: Dashboard Mystery Light]

The light can be switched on or off by operation of the stem on the right of the steering wheel, the same control that operates the windshield wipers.

I can't detect any difference whether it is on or off.

Comment: It will be in the owners manual if you have one. Kind of looks like a throttle body, but can't say I've ever seen anything like it.

Comment: @raydowe throttle body, good idea, so could it be carb heat or manifold heat?

Comment: Now I'm really interested in what this symbol is.  Does the switch  that operates it have any markings on it?  If you figure it out, please let us know.

Answer (score 5):

That light indicates the Exhaust Brake feature is active and will work to slow the vehicle when your foot is taken off the accelerator. 
The picture is meant to be a throttle plate in the closed position (the horizontal line with the dot in the middle) and air being stopped by the plate (the vertical lines).

Here is a question on another site that describes it:

> It has 2 uses. In the winter you flip a switch and the hot exhaust goes back through the engine to warm it up faster. When driving down the road you take your foot off the throttle and a switch kicks in to redirect the exhaust to help slow the truck down. Saves on the brakes if you not a speedster.

https://www.lawnsite.com/threads/bought-an-isuzu-npr-now-i-have-questions.224065/

And this is a product image of the turn signal switch for that truck from Amazon whose description says:

> List Price Is Over Than $300.00 It Has The **Exhaust Brake Switch** For Diesel Engine.

[image]

Comment: Quoting the actual info from that thread you linked (otherwise this is almost a link-only answer): "It has 2 uses. In the winter you flip a switch and the hot exhaust goes back through the engine to warm it up faster. When driving down the road you take your foot off the throttle and a switch kicks in to redirect the exhaust to help slow the truck down. Saves on the brakes if you not a speedster."

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks for pointing out that quote.  I answered what the light was and what the picture was supposed to be, but that quote also helps explain the feature.

Comment: Yeah, your detective work was already enough to go look up the feature by its name, nice find.  But it only felt like half an answer to give the name but not describe what it does, because that's totally non-obvious to curious non-truck-experts.

Answer (score 1):

DPF System Diesel Particulate Filter, If the light is green, it means your system is on, and if it is amber, there is something wrong with the system. Some cars have yet another indicator to let you know when the system is off, and this one will be yellow.